# Spring & Jackson: Exclude all properties, but specify certain ones to include

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following Spring Controller Declaration

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pub/searchparm", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml" })
    public SearchResult search(HttpServletRequest request) {

public class SearchResult {

   private int size;

   private Collection<result> results;

...

}
```

I need to make Jackson default to ignore all the properties on the objects in the Collection by default just for this controller method.

I have looked at @JsonView, @JsonFilter... etc. Jackson includes all properties from the object by default but I have sensitive information that I want to expose only from secure urls. This url is public and I only want some of the properties exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson `@JsonView` support in Spring MVC.
Note that Spring MVC support chose to set `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION`, so that only `@JsonView` annotated attributes are serialized.

See [this blog post on Jackson support in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring).